# How to get a "recyle bin" for Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks

Every once in a while I delete a bookmark in Firefox which turns out to be needed later. Or I simply click "Delete" by mistake.

Is there a addon or built-in config/hack/whatever for Firefox which moves deleted bookmarks to some kind of "recycle bin" so I can restore it if needed or delete it forever when I want to?

I think Opera has this kind of functionality but I really don't want to switch browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [XMarks plugin](http://www.xmarks.com/), as well as syncing your bookmarks between computers and browsers, also backs up bookmark changes to their server for 6 months allowing you to restore previous bookmarks or bookmark sets.

1. Log in to http://my.xmarks.com/ and select 'Tools > Explore & Restore Old Bookmarks...'
2. Select a previous bookmark set from the list of dates
3. Click 'View' and you'll get a HTML page with your old bookmarks from that date. From here you can find any you've lost and bookmark them again.

You also have the option to export bookmark sets to a HTML document or have them overwrite your current set.

Comment: I'd stick with this option.

Comment: Looks like an interesting service. Does it allow to select single bookmarks to restore or do have to import a whole "set"?

Comment: It has to e the whole set, as far as I know.

Comment: You can restore a single bookmark using the procedure above.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but Bookmarks > Organize Bookmarks > Import and Backup > Restore.

What was added since last backup can be found in Bookmarks tab > Recently Bookmarked

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. The problem is that you have to import the whole backup and there is no way to select specific bookmarks to restore.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, Firefox keeps multiple backup copies of your bookmarks in C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\bookmarkbackups.  Take a look there to see if the json files have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that XMarks is the way to go. I also used it, when it was known as foxmarks. And you can now restore different dates of your bookmarks, as it is keeping history of your bookmarks. I never tried it myself, but it should work. I also really like the fact that those are compatible between Linux and Windows. I often find interesting content at work, but I don't have time to review it at work, so I bookmark those, and then review those at home.